# Strategies for Tracing Code Execution in Python, Especially with Event-Driven Libraries

Tags: python, debugging, trace, event-driven

I'm currently working with various Python libraries in my projects and often need to trace or debug the code execution to better understand the underlying mechanisms. However, I've found this challenging with some libraries, especially those utilizing event-driven architectures.

One specific case involves a library named [`guidance`](https://github.com/microsoft/guidance). I'm trying to understand how `guidance` sends HTTP requests. With many libraries that use `urllib3`, I can capture these requests by setting proxy environment variables and using MITMProxy:

```bash
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

However, this method doesn't work with the `guidance` library, leading me to believe that it uses a different mechanism for sending HTTP requests. Here is the `guidance` related code that I'm working with:

```py
import guidance

# set the default language model used to execute guidance programs
guidance.llm = guidance.llms.OpenAI("text-davinci-003")

# define a guidance program that adapts a proverb
program = guidance("""Tweak this proverb to apply to model instructions instead.

{{proverb}}
- {{book}} {{chapter}}:{{verse}}

UPDATED
Where there is no guidance{{gen 'rewrite' stop="\\n-"}}
- GPT {{#select 'chapter'}}9{{or}}10{{or}}11{{/select}}:{{gen 'verse'}}""")

# execute the program on a specific proverb
executed_program = program(
    proverb="Where there is no guidance, a people falls,\nbut in an abundance of counselors there is safety.",
    book="Proverbs",
    chapter=11,
    verse=14
)

print(executed_program["rewrite"]
```

I've tried to trace the code execution using VSCode's debugging features, but this proved difficult because `guidance` seems to employ an event loop framework, which complicates tracing.

This issue is not unique to network requests - I've encountered similar problems when working with other functionalities and libraries. Can anyone suggest general strategies or tools for effectively tracing and understanding Python code execution, especially with libraries that utilize event-driven architectures or other complex patterns?

Any insights or advice are greatly appreciated.